# How to start mitmproxy on Windows

Tags: windows, mitmproxy

I am always having trouble getting mitmproxy to work on Windows. Sometimes it just starts up and works and sometimes it doesn't.

Now I haven't been able to start it for a while and I keep getting this error  `Error starting proxy server: OSError(10013, 'An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions', None, 10013, None)` I have tried running the cmd as administrator but no change.

Also I've searched to see if any process is running on port 8080 and only some process with ID of 4 shows up and its listed as System on task manager, with the task kill button all greyed out so I cant stop it.

How can I get it working? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a port conflict.  Run command netstat -na|findstr port, to see if the port is in use.

Try running mitmproxy on any other port that not been used eg 8081